# HTML form field model binding to List<byte> on controller

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, vuejs3

I have an HTML form with a SelectedIDs field like so:

```
<input type="hidden" id="SelectedIDs" name="selectedIDs" v-model="selectedIDs" />
```

As the user interacts with the form, I have Vue/javascript code that updates the value of the hidden field as items are selected or de-selected.  I can update this value to whatever I need it to look like, but I was hoping a simple CSV format (e.g. `selectedIDsArray.toString()`) would be able to be automatically bound.  So the hidden input would have a value of "1,3,5" for example.

My controller looks like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateSelected(List<byte> selectedIDs) { ... }
```

But it doesn't seem to be able to parse the CSV in to a `List<byte>`.  And I can't seem to find any documentation or examples that cover this case.  They seem to want you to define multiple hidden fields and alter the name for each with an index, which doesn't really fit my use case.

Of course, I could just accept selectedIDs as a CSV string, and then manually parse it in to a list.  But this seems like a common need that probably already has a better solution.  Do I need to make some sort of custom binder?  Format the data differently?  Change the way the controller asks/looks for the hidden field?

Comment: Why are you using `byte` to represent a numeric ID value instead of `int`? When people see `byte` or `List<Byte>` they'll think your code intends to handle _raw binary_ content, not lists-of-human-readable numbers.

Comment: Because the ID is a byte, in the database, and in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the only way to do this is to add form elements with an indexer, one for each element of the List, e.g.:

```
SelectedIDs[0]
SelectedIDs[1]
SelectedIDs[2]
```

Its really not that hard to do, just grab a reference to your form, and append input child elements, like so:

```
var form = document.getElementById("multiClass");

for (i=0; i < this.selectedIDs.length; i++){
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = "SelectedIDs[" + i + "]";
    input.value = this.selectedIDs[i];
    form.appendChild(input);
}
```

Then when the form is submitted, the model binder is able to do its job and binds the `List<byte>`.